# Have keyword with arguments as argument

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm trying to create a keyword that runs through a passed in process and then if that process finishes successfully, I log a list of process ids as passed. I'm having issues with the argument layout right now as I continue to get positional argument errors. Is it possible to do this all inline rather than defining everything before hand? I'm trying to keep this as easy to read/write as possible for others that will be writing scripts with this.

The Validate Step keyword is how I'm attempting to got about this but its thinking that the arguments for the step keyword is the positional argument for step_id. Then step_ids aren't taking the list of ids.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TF-1
    [Documentation]   Test Flow 1
    [Tags]  Test-Flow
    Open Application
    Click Element   ${test_element1}
    Validate Step
    ...   step=Click Element   ${test_element2}
    ...   step_ids=abcd-1234   abcd-5678

*** Keywords ***
Validate Step
    [Documentation]    Executes keyword, if keyword ends with a status of "True"/"Pass", ids are marked as passed
    [Arguments]        ${keyword}  @{step_ids}
    ${status}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    ${keyword}
    Log    ${status}
    Run Keyword If    ${status}    Pass Ids    @{step_ids}
    ...   ELSE    Fail Ids    @{step_ids}

Pass Ids
    [Arguments]    @{ids}
    Log    ${ids} passed

Fail Ids
    [Arguments]    @{ids}
    Log    ${ids} failed
```

Comment: I feel you are too preoccupied whether you can, not if you should. Robot Framework `Run Keyword and Return Status` keyword does not accept a string that contains the keyword and its parameters. You need to separate the keyword and its parameters into two variables.  If you need to accept two or more parameters for keyword, things can become complicated. You could split "Click Element   ${test_element2}" into two variables and pass them for Run Keyword, but once again, it will require strict syntax.

Comment: That is the main thing that I am running into is that I would like to be able to pass in any keyword, no matter how many arguments, and know if it passed or not. I'm just trying to have this framework as easy to follow as possible so having an argument for keyword and an argument for the ids that are associated with that keyword would make that much simpler. It could be broken up with just running Run Keyword and Return Status and then call pass/fail with the result but having a unified method would be ideal with the amount of times it going to end up being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: Robot Framework does not handle variables with spaces very well, and you mix positional and named variables. This is the best workaround I was able to make. It takes advantage of args and kwargs. Step_ids must be a comma-separated list of processes.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    String

*** Keywords ***
Validate Step
    [Arguments]                     @{args}   &{params}
    Log To Console                  ${params}
    ${keyword}=                     Remove From List    ${args}    0
    Run Keyword And Return Status   ${keyword}    @{args}
    ${step_ids_s}=                  Get From Dictionary    ${params}    step_ids
    ${step_ids}=                    Split String    ${step_ids_s}    ,
    Log To Console                  ${step_ids}

*** Test Cases ***
TF-1
    Validate Step    LogMany    foo    bar   baz    step_ids=abcd-1234,abcd-5678
```